# ORDER BY vs SORT BY in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.4 and use the `%sql` mode to query tables.

If I am using a Window function on a large data-set, then which one between `ORDER BY` vs `SORT BY` will be more efficient from a query **performance** standpoint ?

I understand that `ORDER BY` ensures global ordering but the computation gets pushed to only `1` reducer. However, `SORT BY` will sort within each partition but the partitions may receive overlapping ranges.

I want to understand if `SORT BY` too could be used in this case ? And Which one will be more efficient while processing a large data-set (say `100 M` rows) ?

For e.g.

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prsn_id ORDER BY purch_dt desc) AS RN`

VS

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prsn_id SORT BY purch_dt desc) AS RN`

Can anyone please help. Thanks.

Comment: please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603202/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-and-orderby-functions-in-spark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between sort and orderBy functions in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603202/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-and-orderby-functions-in-spark)

Comment: Wires crossed here.

Answer (score 0):

- It does not matter whether you use `SORT BY` or `ORDER BY`. There is a notion about Hive that you are likely referring to, but you are using Spark, that has no such issue.
- For `partition BY` ...the 1 Reducer aspect is only an issue if you have nothing to partition by. You do have *prsn_id*, so not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

`sort by` is applied at each bucket and does not guarantee that entire dataset is sorted.
But `order by` is applied at entire dataset (in a single reducer).
Since your query is partitioned and sorted/ordered for each partition key, the both usage returns the same output.